# How to retrieve not supported styles with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to use Javascript to get a css value from an unsupported property?

**example:** Google chrome version 18 does not support `vh` but would it still be possible to get the value from the css?

Comment: any property in a browser that does not support it would come out null when requesting it. since the css runs in the browsers framework

Comment: So there really is no way of doing it then?

Comment: I don't have an old browser to test it myself :/

Comment: would'nt it help perhaps moving then to a css2 spec for the unsupported property? using height instead of vh? I know the feeling of clients using old browsers. We were stuck with internet explorer 7 at one stage. :/ I would only suggest changing to the earlier specification if it is a requirement from your client. otherwise ask them to update :D?

Comment: It's no required but the layout currently cannot be done with just %'s :(

Comment: I read that apparently there was a way to retrieve unsupported css properties that the user agent does not support. But the spec was dropped by W3. Perhaps if you use your containers with some dynamics you can do this cause i know that using % can sometimes cause undesirable experiences if the user re-sizes his browser. Maybe look into shaping your containers and using max and min height. Cant really tell if you don't expose your current problems.

Comment: Problem  is that % doesn't do anything at all, it doesn't change the size of my element

Comment: well remember that % is context specific so it will size to whatever the size is in its container, so if your main div is 500px, and element inside will never get larger than that if you give it 100% for instance. If your element is at the top of the dom then you should be able to manipulate the size, also note that the percentage needs a sort of size in its main container to work effectively. so if your body is set to 100% of the page size, and you set something to 100% inside your body it would be the page size.

Comment: The element it's parent does not have a set height, nor does the parent's parent

Comment: well if it really is a necessity you can look at this then maybe http://joaocunha.github.io/vunit/

Comment: Also, I've just tried setting the parent's heights, but these ignore %'s too :/

Comment: I did a bit of searching now and aside form using the vh, javascript will be your best bet then if you cant achieve this with css.

Comment: Yeah, thanks :D I'm creating my own small polyfill ^^

Answer (score 0):

If your browser does not support a style it would not know which style you are requesting because the browser does not know what style if it doesn't have the style in its program

Comment: I mean, it does have the style just not the viewport unit